# How to extract a string from <strong> tag under href tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this[1] webpage. I want to extract string 'WORK FROM HOME,PACKING'. I am
unable to get to the strong tag using this code below.I am using Beautiful Soup.

```
 job = soup.find('li', class_='clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')

 job_name = job.header.h2.a.find_all('strong',_class="blkclor")

 print(job_name)
```

> Result  = [] (NONE)

> Expected result: WORK FROM HOME,PACKIMG

this is the link
[1] https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=work+from+home&txtLocation=

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
r = requests.get("https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=work+from+home&txtLocation=")

b = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for i in b.select("h2>a"):
    print(i.text.strip())
```